# cameraX focus is not accurate

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm creating a custom camera app and trying to add focus feature like below

```
val factory = SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory(
                 viewFinder.width.toFloat(),
                 viewFinder.height.toFloat()
              )
val point = factory.createPoint(event.x, event.y)

try {
    cameraControl?.cancelFocusAndMetering()
    val action = FocusMeteringAction.Builder(point, FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF)
                 .setAutoCancelDuration(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                 .build()
}
```

The focusing is not accurate, as you can see below the white circle where I tapped to focus the pen and look where it got focused.

The distance between the tap and focus is pretty large. That was not the case with my default camera app.

[image] [image]

How to adjust focusing to the point where I Tap on `PreviewView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera isn't accurately acquiring focus on the tap region because the conversion `SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory` is performing from UI coordinates to normalized sensor rect coordinates is probably incorrect. The conversion should also take into consideration things like `PreviewView`'s layout direction, scale type, the device's rotation and whether the camera is front/back facing. `SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory` doesn't do that. If you're curious what the conversion looks like, check out [`PreviewViewMeteringPointFactory`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:camera/camera-view/src/main/java/androidx/camera/view/PreviewViewMeteringPointFactory.java?q=PreviewViewMeteringPointFactory&ss=androidx).

`PreviewView` already provides a metering point factory that handles the conversion internally, you can call [`PreviewView.getMeteringPointFactory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView#getMeteringPointFactory()) and pass it the tap coordinates.

Comment: [`PreviewView.getMeteringPointFactory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView#getMeteringPointFactory()) has been around for a while, it's in CameraX's view artifact (`camera-view`), not its core artifact (`camera-core`). So make sure to include `androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha19` as a dependency in your app. It's true that there isn't much official docs for `PreviewView`. You can take a look at [this post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/display-a-camera-preview-with-previewview-86562433d86c), it goes over it, even though it's not up to date.

Comment: Finally I got it, `val point = idViewFinder.meteringPointFactory.createPoint(event.x, event.y)`